# Effect of not using clWaitForEvents

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCL programming. In one of my OpenCL applications, I use clWaitForEvents after launching every kernel.

Case 1:

```
time_start();
cl_event event;
cl_int status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, ..., &event);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
time_end();
```

Time taken : 250 ms (with clWaitForEvents)

If I remove clWaitForEvents(), my kernel runs faster with the same output.

Case 2:

```
time_start();
cl_event event;
cl_int status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, ..., &event);
time_end();
```

Time taken: 220 ms (without clWaitForEvents)

I've to launch 10 different kernels sequentially. Every kernel is dependent on the output of the previous kernel. Using clWaitForEvent after every kernel increases my execution time by few 100 ms.

Can the outputs go wrong if I do not use clWaitForEvents? I would like to understand what might possibly go wrong if I do not use clWaitForEvents or clFinish.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Single in-order queue doesn't need wait event.

Comment: Unless there is an async command like clEnqueueReadBuffer(..false..) with "blocking" not enabled.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik AFAIK actually a non-blocking clEnqueueReadBuffer() is not an "async" command, the blocking parameter is merely for convenience; it will still execute in-order if the queue is in-order. It's the same as calling clEnqueueReadBuffer(); clFinish();

Comment: @mogu he said `Can the outputs go wrong if I do not use clWaitForEvents`. Then he has to use blocking buffer read or clfinish(). Otherwise outputs can go wrong from host's point of view but ofcourse from GPU's point of view everything is ok. He didn't get in detail if he is using data from host side. `clWaitForEvent` is for waiting from host side right? If no host sync is needed, just passing event to next command's event list is enough for that command to wait on device side only(not sync with host) (but this is pointless with an in-order queue, ofcourse)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik & mogu Thank you for your feedback. I do not need host sync until all the kernels are finished. I'm using an in-order queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully a slightly less complicated answer:

> I've to launch 10 different kernels sequentially. Every kernel is dependent on the output of the previous kernel.

If you don't explicitly set CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE property in clCreateCommandQueue() call (= the usual case), it will be an in-order queue. You don't need to synchronize commands in them (actually you shouldn't, as you see it can considerably slow down execution). See the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html):

`If the CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE property of a command-queue is not set, the commands enqueued to a command-queue execute in order. For example, if an application calls clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to execute kernel A followed by a clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to execute kernel B, the application can assume that kernel A finishes first and then kernel B is executed. If the memory objects output by kernel A are inputs to kernel B then kernel B will see the correct data in memory objects produced by execution of kernel A.`

> I would like to understand what might possibly go wrong if I do not use clWaitForEvents or clFinish.

If you're doing simple stuff on a single in-order queue, you don't need clWaitForEvents() at all. It's mostly useful if you want to wait for multiple events from multiple queues, or you're using out-of-order queues, or you want to enqueue 20 commands but wait for the 4th, or something similar.

For a single in-order queue, after clFinish() returns all commands will be completed and any&all events will have their status updated to complete or failed. So in the simplest case you don't need to deal with events at all, just enqueue everything you need (check the enqueues for errors though) and call clFinish().

Note that if you don't use any form of wait/flush (WaitForEvents / Finish / a blocking command), the implementation may take as much time as it wants to actually push those commands to a device. IOW you **must** either 1) use WaitForEvents or Finish, or 2) enqueue a blocking command (read/write/map/unmap) as the **last** command.

Comment: usaing an WaitForEvents or Finish is increasing the execution time. Is there any alternative "dummy" blocking command that can be used? Is it OK to add a "dummy" blocking read ?

Comment: @svg you don't have to use finish/wait after *every* kernel launch, but you have to use *at least one* at the end, otherwise you don't know when the results are ready. A blocking read on a single in-order command queue is the same as wait/finish, so it won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

`In-order-queue` implicitly waits for each command completion in the order they are enqueued but only on device-side. This means host can't know what happened.

`Out-of-order-queue` does not guarantee any command order in anywhere and can have issues.

'Wait-for-event' waits on host side for an event of a command.

'Finish' waits on host side until all commands are complete.

'Non blocking buffer read/write' does not wait on host side.

'Blocking buffer read/write' waits on host side but does not wait for other commands.

---

Recommended solutions:

- Inter-command sync (for using output of a command as input of next command)

  - in-order-queue.
  - or passing event of a command to another (if its an out-of-order queue)
- Inter-queue(or out-of-order queue) sync (for overlapping buffer copies and kernel executions)

  - pass events from command(s) to another command
- Device - host sync (for getting latest data to RAM(or getting first data from RAM) or pausing host)

  - enable blocking option on buffer commands
  - or add a clFinish
  - or use clWaitForEvent
- Be informed when a command is complete(for reasons like benchmarking)

  - use event callback
  - or constantly query event state(CPU/pci-e usage increases)

---

Enqueueing 1 non-blocking buffer write + 1000 x kernels + 1 blocking buffer read on an in-order-queue can successfully execute a chain of 1000 kernels on initial data and get latest results on host side.